# Problem while using pre tag

Tags: html

In my project we need to display code snippet, so I am using pre and code(both) tag.

### **PROBLEM**

While displaying the code snippet it is displaying white spaces before and after the actual content. How to remove these white spaces before and after the snippet.

Answer (score 10):

Remove the whitespace inside your pre tag.

Example:

```
<pre>
  This is a test.

  We want a new line here.
</pre>
```

should be

```
<pre>This is a test.

We want a new line here.</pre>
```

Answer (score 3):

With HTML 5 pre tag doesnt supported anymore if you want to use its features.
Make your own css class like this...

```
.pre
{
border: 1px solid #999;
page-break-inside: avoid;
display: block;
padding: 3px 3px 2px;
margin: 0 0 10px;
font-size: 13px;
line-height: 20px;
word-break: break-all;
word-wrap: break-word;
/*white-space: pre;
white-space: pre-wrap;*/
background-color: #f5f5f5;
border: 1px solid #ccc;
border: 1px solid rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.15);
-webkit-border-radius: 4px;
-moz-border-radius: 4px;
border-radius: 4px;
font-family: Monaco, Menlo, Consolas, "Courier New", monospace;
font-size: 12px;
color: #333333;
}

.pre code
{
    padding: 0;
    color: inherit;
    white-space: pre;
    white-space: pre-wrap;
    background-color: transparent;
    border: 0;
}
```

Cancelling `/*white-space: pre;
    white-space: pre-wrap;*/` will make your white spaces works like div.
use it as a class to give the same look to your elements.

Answer (score 1):

The `<pre>` tag is for pre-formatted text. That means you need to do the formatting yourself - *all* of it, including making sure the whitespace is exactly what you want to display. Don't output excess whitespace between your `<pre>` tags and the content inside of them.

Answer (score 0):

You need to make sure the code is formatted correctly, the pre tag tells the browser to show the text inside the pre "as is".

A little thing that I my self has found useful is to use this php to import the file so I don't have to cut and paste all the time.

```
<?php
$file = "code/hello_world.c";
print "<p>Filename: <a href=\"".$file."\">".$file."</a></p>\n";
print "<div class=\"codebox\"><pre>\n\n";
$lines = file($file); foreach ($lines as $line_num => $line)
{ 
    echo htmlspecialchars($line) . ""; 
}
print "\n</pre></div>\n";
?>
```

And then to make it look like code I add this in my css

```
PRE {
    font-family:    'Monotype.com', Courier New, monospace;
    font-size:  0.7em;
}

.codebox {
    width: 90%;
    background-color: #000000;
    color: #FFFFFF;
}

.codebox pre {
    margin:      0 0 0  20px;
}
```

Maybe you find it helpful.